# Time Attendances query in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access, time-and-attendance

I'm having troubles with writing a query in Microsoft Access. 
This is how my table looks like and where i want to retrieve data from:

[image]

I want to write a query that has the following result:

[image]

As you can see in the first table an employee can check IN and OUT more than 2 times a day. When a employee checks in for the first time the Date/time should be placed in the first colum "CheckIn". When he checks in for the second time the Date/time should be placed in the second column "CheckOut". When he checks in for the 3th time the Date/time should be placed in the column "CheckIn" and so on.

I have learned from my previous question that I can use a subquery and the modulus operator for a similar situation like this. But I can't figure out how i can make the query work for the problem above.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: That data structure is a bit inadequate - shouldn't it have a column to denote whether the entry is for a check in or a check out?

Comment: I will keep this in mind for the next time i post a question @jarlh, thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Yes i figured. I was wondering if it was possible without this column.

Comment: @jarlh - yes, can't even see the images here so haven't got a chance at answering.  Seems the OP has an answer already though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the answer from the previous question, and work our way from there.

This query defines if it's a check in, or check-out. Let's call it qryCheckInOut

```
SELECT EmployeeID, 
    timeInOut, 
    IIF(
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM MyTable s 
        WHERE s.EmployeeID = m.EmployeeID 
        AND s.timeInOut <= m.timeInOut
        AND s.timeInOut >= INT(m.timeInOut)) Mod 2 = 1, "I", "O") As OriginType
FROM MyTable m
```

Then, we can get the check-ins from that query, and use a subquery to get the check-outs.

We use conditions to make sure the check out is on the same day, and later than the check in, and use the `Min` aggregate to make sure it's the next time (the lowest possible time).

```
SELECT q.EmployeeID, 
    q.TimeInOut As TimeIn,
    (SELECT Min(s.TimeInOut)
    FROM qryCheckInOut s
    WHERE s.EmployeeID = q.EmployeeId
    AND s.TimeInOut > q.TimeInOut
    AND s.TimeInOut <= Int(q.TimeInOut) + 1) As TimeOut
FROM qryCheckInOut q
WHERE q.OriginType = 'I'
```

Note that, in the subquery of the second query, you don't need to check if it's a check in or check out, since the lowest time higher than the check in on the same day always is a check out.

If you want to do it in a single query, you can use the query below. However, it will be substantially harder to debug

```
SELECT m.EmployeeID, 
    m.TimeInOut As TimeIn,
    (SELECT Min(s.TimeInOut)
    FROM MyTable s
    WHERE s.EmployeeID = m.EmployeeId
    AND s.TimeInOut > m.TimeInOut
    AND s.TimeInOut <= Int(m.TimeInOut) + 1) As TimeOut
FROM MyTable m
WHERE 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM MyTable s 
    WHERE s.EmployeeID = m.EmployeeID 
    AND s.timeInOut <= m.timeInOut
    AND s.timeInOut >= INT(m.timeInOut)) Mod 2 = 1
```

Comment: Thanks alot Erik. Your answer has helped me alot.